# Completely exporting a WhatsApp chat, including media and voice messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat-history

I have a chat with a lot of voice messages, pictures and chat messages that I would like to completely export to my laptop, so that I can listen to the voice messages, view the pictures and read the complete chat history.

The 'email chat' option only exports a small portion of the text and voice messages and just 8-10 pictures. As for the 'back up chats' option - I don't know what to do with the created files - as far as I understood from googling, they are meant to be read by WhatsApp itself - not by you on a PC/Laptop.

Thank you for any help!

Update:

Kind of a solution: Decoding the WhatsApp encrypted backups - [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/decrypting-whatsapp-crypt8-v2-12-38-t3083847)

Comment: user1482714 i wanted to know how to decode the backup if u can help me, thank u in advance

Comment: I don't remember anymore but you need some application that can open the db files (or whatever it was that one gets out of it). I used something called DB browser for SQlite for Ubuntu

Comment: Not really Android stuff but you can export your chat from WhatsApp Web using this browser extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backup-whatsapp-chats/gmbicfpadlmgkfhfepknbmemfhahelll. Will include all the media sent in the chat as well.